# Find maximum of multiple numbers in Matlab

Tags: matlab, comparison, max

This may be a very trivial question. How can I get the maximum number from three or four numbers in mat-lab. This numbers are not elements of a matrix. I tried the max(a,b,c,d), but this used only in the MuPAD Notebook Interface. Any help please?

Comment: Put them in a array, `A = [a b c d]` and perform `max(A)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do them in one instruction:

```
a=1; b=2; c=3; d=2;
res = max([a b c d]);
```

res will be 3 !